# Custom formats using CSS stylesheet

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I know I can link a style sheet to TinyMCE and this will be used when I am editing. It also seems to apply the styling to the Heading options available in the format dropdown list which is great. I also know I can add custom formats menu using `custom_formats` ([here](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/custom_formats.php)) but is there a way for the Formats to be populated using my CSS automatically? I have various classes in my CSS for the P tag and would like to allow my users to utilise them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible (at least not out of the box).
How could a piece of code guess what style or class to use from the pure CSS?

Comment: It's not meant to guess, the idea is to build a list of available classes for the user to select from (like they do when they select Format -> Headings -> H1). The editor I was using previously scanned the style sheet and populated a dropdown with the classes available. Thanks for the info, I will write a module to do it.